# Decrease speed of uitableview scrolling in ios?

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to decrease the speed of UITableView scroll speed.

I've tried using decelerationRate property.
I changed this property to UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal and UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast but couldn't feel the change.

I couldn't figure out any other way to decrease the scroll speed.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please let me know if u found any solution for this ?